# Where to load Tensorflow model in Django application

Tags: python, django, tensorflow

I am working on a Django project that should load a saved Tensorflow model from a file. Where should I run this code to have a global model variable? Currently, I am just loading in the model in the views.py file outside of all functions and it is working, but I am unsure if this runs only once and if it is a clean solution.

Comment: You could try singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start using mlops, and leave everything preloaded as much as you can, so that when you call the api, django only takes care of generating the predict. I leave you here my project, I have several with ML/Django/Tflite.

Models can be grouped in media files, you can even use DVC to your git/bucket/gdrive, to avoid saturating the git repository with large files.
By doing this you don't need to create global variables, just instantiate the model, you can generate predict whenever you want.

If you have any doubt don't hesitate to ask me.

Link to my project: https://github.com/Nouvellie/django-mlops-docker/blob/main/src/main/apps/mlops/utils/model_loader.py